# CSS form border formatting inside PHP file

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I'm trying to embed some CSS into my PHP file. How can I properly add my CSS so that each called form will be rendered inside a black border? This is what I tried so far.

```
 while ($ratings = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
        //This outputs the doctors's name
        echo "Doctor's name:" . $ratings['doctor_name'] ."<br />";

            // Retrieve the id of the doctor which was posted on
            $id = $_POST['id'];

            echo "<style> form { border-style: solid; border-color: #ffffff}"; 

            //This outputs a textarea for the user to submit comments

            echo "<b>Your Experience: </b>";
            echo "<form method='post' action='review_doctors.php'> 

                    <textarea name='body'></textarea>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'/>

                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$ratings[id]' />

                    </style>

                 </form>
                 ";


            echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the form in the style tag? The style tag should only include styles.

Comment: And then your style tag is terminated before the `form` is.  This kills the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: "The style tag should only include styles".

```
?>
<style>
form {
    border: 3px solid black;
}
</style>
<?php
while ($ratings = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    echo "<form>...</form>"
}
```

If you would like to reuse styles you can put them in their own file and then include them on each page:

```
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/mystyle.css">
<?php
// ...
```